# Redox reactions of halides in hexane

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, halides, solvents

When we have two test tubes and we add:

1. In the first test tube: hexane, aqueous solution of $\ce{NaCl}$ and aqueous solution of $\ce{I2}$
2. In the second test tube: hexane, aqueous solution of $\ce{NaI}$ and aqueous solution of $\ce{Cl2}$

We are asked to write the reactions that take place in these experiments. Do we write only this:

$$\ce{NaCl + I2 → no reaction}$$

$$\ce{2NaI + Cl2 → 2NaCl + I2 (displacement)}$$

Or should hexane appear in the reactions too?

Comment: I'd write the reactions the same way you did. What puzzles me is why they bothered to mention hexane at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hexane is the solvent for the two halogens. It does not react with either so leave it out of your answer.